# clear user input text Android

Tags: android

I'm very new to android and could use some help. I have created an app that enables you to add a user (in this case, rider). Upon hitting 'enter', a toast comes up to let the user know that the individual was successfully added. I want the text in the editText box to be cleared. I know that there have been many solutions on here for this, but none of them worked for me; they all kill my app. Any help? Code for reference:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_rider_name);            
        setContentView(R.layout.add_rider_screen);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addRiderButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                editText.setText("");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

"The rider was successfully added!",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the logcat error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.cherryjp.buttonapp, PID: 8297

E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

E/AndroidRuntime: at com.example.cherryjp.buttonapp.AddRiderScreen$1.onClick(AddRiderScreen.java:38)

E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)

E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)

E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)

E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)

E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: "they all kill my app" - what shows up in Logcat when this happens?

Comment: You haven't initialized `editText` anywhere like you do with your `Button`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you didn't initialize your `EditText`, you need to add this line in `onCreate` before you call `setText("")`

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
```

Make sure you put this after you can `setContentView` though

Comment: Thank you.. I was missing this. However, this still causes my app to stop runnning. 
If I comment out: editText.setText("");

Then the app works as planned. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you edit your post with the output from Logcat when your app crashes? That will make it easier to diagnose the problem

Comment: Please edit that into your original post. Can you update your `onCreate` method code to what to you changed?

Comment: Changes have been made. Sorry. New to this

Comment: Ok, the fix is easy. You need to initialize your `EditText` and any future views *after* `setContentView(R.layout.add_rider_screen);`

Answer (score 0):

Just as Andrew Brooke said,

You have initialized your editText before

`setContentView(R.layout.add_rider_screen);`

initialize your editText after that and you are good to go.....

Do something like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.add_rider_screen);
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_rider_name);
```